# Enums a Good Approach for API Routing Constants?

Tags: java, android, enums

I'm converting over an old android app right now where a lot of developers had a lot of different ideas that never quite met in the middle. A common pattern in the app was to define a list of constant strings for API routes. For example: `Public Static final String HOME_FEED = "/%s/home"` These were used for constructing API URls with volley HTTP Requests, something like `String route = String.format(Requests.HOME_FEED, user.getUserId());` Activities would then subscribe to an event bus and wait for the Volley Response that sent the Json response object and a response code. Every API String Constant had a Corresponding Int Constant response code like so `Public Static final int HOME_FEED_GET = 0;` My Proposal to avoid these two constant classes and couple them together is something like this

```
public enum Requests {
HOME_FEED           (0, "/actions/users/%s/following"),
PROFILE_FEED        (0, "/actions/users/%s"),
CLUB_FEED           (0, "/actions/clubs/%s"),

LIKE_ITEM           (1, "/items/%s/like"),
LIKE_UPDATE         (1, "/updates/%s/like"),
LIKE_COLLECTION     (1, "/collections/%s/like"),

COMMENTS_ITEM       (2, "/items/%s/comments"),
COMMENTS_UPDATE     (2, "/comments/%s/update"),
COMMENTS_COLLECTION (2, "/collections/%s/comments");

private final int requestCode;
private final String route;

Requests(int requestCode, String route) {
    this.requestCode = requestCode;
    this.route = route;
}

public int requestCode() {return requestCode;}

public String route() {return route;}
}
```

Which would make the route construction for volley read `String url = String.format(Requests.HOME_FEED.route(), user.getUserId())` and then any subscribed event bus would be passed `Requests.HOME_FEED.requestCode` Does this approach sound feasible or am I just over engineering here?

Comment: Honestly, using a library that's already made these decisions (and made them well) is your best answer. Retrofit solves this dilemma eloquently.

Comment: @ElliotM I am not tied to using Volley at all actually. It is just currently what is in use. It seems like the community has leaned away from volley in favor of other libraries such as Retrofit. Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: I believe that's a fair assumption.